# The profile image in flair for IS is missing

Tags: support

I just noticed that my IS flair is missing the profile image.

[image]

All other flair, including my meta has the image.

[image]

I didn't observe closely, so I can't say if it disappeared at the same time as the SE server was down, or if it was after that. I know it was working earlier in the day, however.

Other than posting here in meta, is there somewhere else I should raise the issue?

Comment: Looks like they're both missing for you... Mine seems to be fine, however?

Comment: Thanks for looking. Seems that now both are there now. Since I'm still new, however, the real question still exists. Is this the place to go, or is there somewhere else one should go from problems like that? Maybe MSE?

Comment: Yeah, this is the right place, or you could go to MSE if it concerns all sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue - linked to the S3 outage.

Read this post on meta.se for more info:

[Intermittent Failed to upload image; imgur is rejecting the request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291609/154443)